# What's the best practice to work on Wordpress locally?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I have a simple Wordpress website that is created using twelve twenty. I need to transfer it from server to my PC to be able to edit it and transfer it back to server. Now that I copied wordpress directory from server to my PC it asks me to reinstall it. How can I do it? Am I missing something? Is it possible to work on website locally and once it is done transger it to the server?

Reason for doing this are:
-don't want to loss data for wrong doing things.
-have a copy of website on local machine.
-easier to work on the local machine offline rather than bing online and accssing the server.

Comment: Firstly you'll need to back everything up, back up your SQL database from the current server and then download all the files from the web server to your local machine. 

Once you've taken this back up, store it somewhere useful, you'll need this in case anything goes wrong. 

Now you can duplicate all the website files and place them in your development folder (htdocs if using mamp). Create the database & user on your local machine and import the the export you took. 

Make sure you don't touch the backup you made as this is your safety net in case anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view , i would suggest u to back-up full website and database from server [every hosting control panels has option to backup same]
Connect via ftp and  edit ur files.. there to make lots of changes when u want to move from local to server or server to local.
cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Editing the files on a live site directly is a terrible, *terrible* idea. It invites any number of points of failure. If you're actively developing a site things *will break* at some point - it's part of the developing process - and you definitely want to break things locally, not on a live site.

There's actually several steps involved, all of which are too long to go into great detail, but here's an overview of what is required along with a few links to get you started. The first time you do it seems laborious, but once you figure it all out it actually only takes 10 minutes.

1. Firstly you will need a local environment MySQL and PHP environment to install it. As you're on PC look at WAMP; [here's a fairly good tutorial on installing it.](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-your-windows-computer-using-wamp/)
2. If you have a lot of content on the live site you might want to import it into your local environment; you'll need to export the database (probably using PHPMyAdmin) and then import it into your local database. You will need to update a couple of database options so that it points towards your localhost. It's basically [the reverse of the process detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343558/installing-wordpress-on-another-hosting/27346157#27346157): you'll be changing `your-site.com` to `localhost:8888`. If your site is relatively simple you could skip this stage*
3. Now you should be able to update your local copy of `wp-config.php` with the database connect details for your local database (usually it's just `localhost` for the host name and `root` for the user and password`). With that in place you should now be able to install WP.
4. Now that it's installed you can edit away to your heart's content on your local copy, safe in the knowledge that anything you do on your local copy doesn't affect your live copy. When you're ready to push your changes live you can use FTP to copy your local files to your live environment.

---

* For a lot of projects I don't actually go to the trouble of synching databases - if there's a live site that the client can change the content on it often becomes a futile exercise attempting to synch a database with a moving target. In those instances I'll just use a comprehensive set of test content that contains every conceivable type of content that could possible inserted in to the live site.

Answer (score 0):

your going to love working on your project from your locally. Here's an article I found on wpmudev http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-install-wordpress-locally-for-pcwindows-with-xampp/ which gives you a step by step guide for PC / Windows.